# Flipping a sprite in OpenGL... with an x origin... (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, math

I've managed to be able to flip sprites in OpenGL:

```
// ox is origin x, w is width, flip is whether the sprite should flipped

if (flip) {
    x += (w+ox);
}

x += ox;
y += oy;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

//bottom right
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(x, y);
//top right
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(flip ? x - w : x + w, y);
//top left
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(flip ? x - w : x + w, y + h);
//bottom left
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(x, y + h);

glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

It *works*, but something is wrong with flipping sprites based on their origin. The sprite displays fine just how it should look when it's faced in the positive x direction (not flipped). But as soon as I flip it, all of the sprite positions (I'm using an animation of sprites) don't align just as they do when not flipped. What I'm trying to do is literally, just flip it with the origin flipped just right. If you don't get what I mean...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY8rZEyjR4s (video of the problem in action)

I've tried so much random math at this point, I don't know what to even try next, and of course I tried basic things like `x += flip ? -ox : ox;` and I messed with the `x += (w+ox);` line too.

And I'm adding this because someone asked it in a comment, this is what I mean by origin:

for example I would do setOrigin(-1,2) on the sprite and it would move -1 pixels on the x axis (left 1 pixel if not flipped) and 2 pixels on the y axis (down 2 pixels)

Comment: can you tell me what your definition of "origin" is? as far as I can guess, it's the upper left of the sprite... but I don't know if that's meant to be that way

Comment: for example I would do setOrigin(-1,2) on the sprite and it would move -1 pixels on the x axis (left 1 pixel if not flipped) and 2 pixels on the y axis (down 2 pixels)

Comment: What about flipping the texture coordinates instead of the vertices? Otherwise I'm not sure (sorry, but I can't tell what's wrong from your video).

Comment: You want to your image in the same place, just flipped horizontally, then I believe that instead of `x += (w + ox)` it should be only `x += w`.